# Date formatting in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got a datetime from an XML file of this format:

```
<LastFetchTime>2011-03-25T00:09:09+08:00</LastFetchTime>
```

And when I parse and convert it into a C# datetime using this code:

```
lastAppliedDate = DateTime.Parse(xmlInput.Descendants("LastFetchTime").First().Value);
```

I get

{3/24/2011 12:09:09 PM}

Which I think is odd, since +8 ought to move you forward, not back.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears +8 is the time zone associated with the time, and what you get is GMT.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a bonehead (see above comment.)

Answer (score 1):

The +8 refers to the offset from GMT so you must be -1 thus you get it in your time zone.

Comment: Thanks!  My eyes were dropping the two leading 00s and I was seeing it as 9:09.  Then panic set in.   I'm actually -4 EST.

Comment: (And +1 but Z won the coin toss.)